# Conflict between Laravel 5.7.1 and Forms & HTML package?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, terminal, composer-php

I tried to install Forms & HTML in Laravel Framework 5.7.1 using this command:

`composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.2.0"`

I get this error message:

`Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.`

with these errors thrown:

`Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.7.1`

`Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.1`

?? I'm *in* the framework. Am I supposed completely start over from scratch with an earlier version of Laravel? Why doesn't this common package work with 5.7.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third-party packages often need to make changes when a new Laravel version drops. 5.7 released just a couple hours ago, and [5.7 support is in review for that package](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/pull/565).

Comment: Is there an easy way to downgrade to an earlier version, or do I need to start over?

Comment: I'd just wait a little bit for the package to be updated, or do without it entirely - it's a nice package, but it's not required.

Comment: You might not know this, but it's a standard package, do you think it will be ready in the next week or so, or could it take a month+?

Comment: It's not a standard package. That's why it's in `laravelcollective`, not `laravel`. I'd expect them to be pretty quick. See https://laravelcollective.com/: "We maintain Laravel components that have been removed from the core framework, so you can continue to use the amazing Laravel features that you love."

Comment: Okay, Thank you!